# jQuery draggable not work containment

Tags: jquery, html, draggable

I use `draggable` for a div

But `containment` not working in `function`

```
$("#main").draggable({
    start : function() {
      var ps = $('#ps').val();
      containment:[-1000,-1000,ps,ps]
    }
});
```

I want `var ps` use in `draggable` because this value change after

Comment: what ?! please explain more